# Problem in implementing multiple threading for operations on a linked list

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, critical-section, readwritelock

In the following code, I tried handling various linked list operations using multiple threads. Multiple linked lists can be supported and all functions are generic except I kept a few `printf` statements to debug the code.

```
typedef void (*gen_fun_t)(void *);

ll_t thread[2];
int ret;

#define RWLOCK(lt, lk) (ret=(lt) == l_read)? pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&(lk)): pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&(lk))
#define RWUNLOCK(lk) pthread_rwlock_unlock(&(lk));

typedef enum locktype locktype_t;

enum locktype
{
    l_read,
    l_write
};

struct node
{
    void *val;

    struct node  *next;

    pthread_rwlock_t m;
};


struct ll
{
        int len;

        struct node *head;
        pthread_rwlock_t m;

        gen_fun_t val_teardown;

        gen_fun_t val_printer;
};
typedef struct ll* ll_t;

typedef struct node * ll_node;

ll_t create( gen_fun_t val_teardown)
{
        ll_t list=(ll_t)malloc(sizeof(struct ll));
        list->head=NULL;
        list->len=0;
        list->val_teardown = val_teardown;

        pthread_rwlock_init(&list->m, NULL);

        return list;
}

ll_node new_node(void *val)
{
        ll_node node= (ll_node)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node->val=val;
        node->next=NULL;
        pthread_rwlock_init(&node->m, NULL);

        return node;
}


int remove_mid(ll_t list, int n)
{
        printf("Before deletion \n");
        print(list);
        ll_node temp;
        if(n==0)
        {
                temp=list->head;
                list->head=temp->next;
                printf("%d \n", *(int *)(list->head)->val);
        }
        else
        {
                ll_node it;
                it=list->head;
                for(;n>1;n--)
                        it=it->next;
                printf("%d \n", *(int *)(it->next)->val);
                temp=it->next;
                it->next=it->next==NULL? NULL: temp->next;
                printf("%d \n", *(int *)(it->next)->val);
        }
        (list->len)--;

        list->val_teardown(temp->val);
        free(temp);
        return list->len;
}

int insert_mid(ll_t list, void *val, int n)
{
        ll_node node= new_node(val);

        if(n==0)
        {
                node->next=list->head;
                list->head=node;
        }
        else
        {
                ll_node it;
                it=list->head;
                for(;n>1;n--)
                        it=it->next;
                node->next=it->next;
                it->next=node;
                printf("After insertion \n");
                print(list);
                printf("\n");
        }
        (list->len)++;
        return list->len;
}

void *thread_operation(void * arg)
{
        long id= (long) arg;

        if(id==0)
        {
                        RWLOCK(l_write, list[0]->m);
                        //RWLOCK(l_read, list[0]->m);
                        printf("The status of lock operation is %d \n", ret);
                        printf("\nThread: %ld \n", id);
                        int v=rand()%100;
                        int pos=rand()%list[0]->len;
                        printf("The position inserted is %d \n",pos+1);
                        pos=insert_mid(list[0], &v, pos);
                        //RWUNLOCK(list[0]->m);
                        RWUNLOCK(list[0]->m);

        }
        else
        {
                        RWLOCK(l_write, list[0]->m);
                        //RWLOCK(l_read, list[0]->m);
                        printf("The status of lock operation is %d \n", ret);
                        printf("\nThread: %ld \n", id);
                        int pos=rand()%list[0]->len;
                        printf("The position to be deleted is %d \n", pos+1);
                        pos=remove_mid(list[0], pos);
                        print(list[0]);
                        //RWUNLOCK(list[0]->m);
                        RWUNLOCK(list[0]->m);
        }
}

int main()
{

        int thread_count=2;
        long thread;
        srand(time(0));

        list[0]= create(int_tear);
        list[0]->val_printer = int_printer;

        list[1]=create(float_tear);
        list[1]->val_printer= float_printer;

        pthread_t *thread_handles;

        int l, a=2, b=8, c=15;

        l=insert_first(list[0], &a);
        l=insert_end(list[0], &b);
        l=insert_mid(list[0], &c, rand()%l);

        double start, finish, elapsed;

        start=clock();

        thread_handles= (pthread_t *) malloc(thread_count*sizeof(pthread_t));

        for(thread=0;thread<thread_count;thread++)
                pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, thread_operation, (void *)thread);

        for(thread=0;thread<thread_count;thread++)
                pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);

        finish=clock();
        elapsed =(finish-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        return 0;
}
```

It gives output as

```
Thread: 0 
The position to be inserted is 3 
After insertion 
ll: 2 15 79 8 


Thread: 1 
The position to be deleted is 1 
Before deletion 
ll: 2 15 -2087655584 8

ll: 15 -2087655584 8
```

Clearly, 79 was inserted in position 2 by the `insert_mid` function but why does it change to -2087655584? What is the solution?

If any information is required, please inform.

Comment: You didn't post the source to create().   While you are doing that, why not add some code to check the return values of pthread_rwlock_{rdlock,wrlock,unlock}().   Try to imagine what your threads would do if these were returning errors, rather than suspending execution.  Also, it makes no sense to do a write lock and read lock on the same operation; write for modify, read for look at.  (that is why I suspect you didn't do a pthread_rwlock_init() in create, so these functions are no-ops).

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but you should not acquire both a read lock and a write lock. If you only want to read the data get a read lock, if you want to write get a write lock and afterwards unlock once. Check the return value to see if you successfully acquired the lock. If you don't hold the lock, the behavior of unlocking is undefined.

Comment: Please show the `new_node` function. Pretty sure you keep a pointer to v, which is allocated on the stack of the first thread you create.

Comment: @Bodo yes you are right. Only write_lock is needed here. I was just trying to debug so I thought why not suspend all operations on the list as apparently the read operation is failing(reading wrong value)

Comment: @mevets I have included the create() function in edits. I had done pthread_rwlock_init() prevoiusly. The return values of acquiring lock is 0, which means everything is ok.

Comment: @numzero. I have included the `new_node` method in edits.

Comment: @Sinister Please add enough code to allow compiling and running your program. see [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short summary:** You store the address of a local variable in a list node and this variable goes out of scope, so the address becomes invalid.

---

Your function `new_node(void *val)` gets an address as an argument and stores this address in the node structure as `node->val`.

In your `main` function you first create 3 nodes with the addresses of local variables.

```
        int l, a=2, b=8, c=15;

        l=insert_first(list[0], &a);
        l=insert_end(list[0], &b);
        l=insert_mid(list[0], &c, rand()%l);
```

These variables are valid until the end of `main`, so there is no problem here.

In this loop

```
        for(thread=0;thread<thread_count;thread++)
                pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, thread_operation, (void *)thread);
```

you create threads running `thread_operation` and pass the loop counter, casted to a `void*` as an argument.

In `thread_operation` when called with argument value 0 you add a node using the address of a local variable `v`

```
void *thread_operation(void * arg)
{
        long id= (long) arg;

        if(id==0)
        {
/* ... */
                        int v=rand()%100;
                        int pos=rand()%list[0]->len;
/* ... */
                        pos=insert_mid(list[0], &v, pos); /* &v is the address of a local variable */
/* ... */
        }
        else
        {
/* ... */
        }
}

/* ... */
int insert_mid(ll_t list, void *val, int n)
{
        ll_node node= new_node(val); /* The address is passed to the new node. */
/* ... */
}
```

When `thread_operation` leaves the body of

```
        if(id==0)
        {
/* ... */
        }
```

the variable goes out of scope and becomes invalid. (If you compile your program without optimization it probably keeps its value until the function returns, but this is not guaranteed.)

When `thread_operation` returns, the stack area where this variable was located is disposed and will be used for other function calls later.

When you print the contents of the list, the node inserted by the thread with ID 0 points to some address on the stack that once held the variable `v` and might be in use or might have been used for something else afterwards. That's why the value gets changed. This is undefined behavior.

To fix this problem you can either change your node structure to **store the value of the variable** as an `int` **instead of the address of the variable** as a `void *` **or** you have to **allocate memory and create a copy of the data** like this

```
ll_node new_node(void *val, size_t size)
{
        ll_node node= (ll_node)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        /* TODO check that malloc did not return NULL */
        node->val = malloc(size);
        /* TODO check that malloc did not return NULL */
        memcpy(node->val, val, size);
        node->next=NULL;
        pthread_rwlock_init(&node->m, NULL);

        return node;
}
```

Additional possible problem:

You create a lock object in every list node. If you want to use this to to protect access to the data in the node, the corresponding thread must get (at least) a read lock for the list to prevent other threads from deleting the node.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.